# Should the smallest element be the greatest lower bound

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

Recently I found the following problem.

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$, $B\subseteq A$ and $b\in B$.
>   Prove that if $b$ is the smallest element of $B$, then it is also the greatest lower bound of $B$.

But how that is possible?

I mean even if we have set $L$ of elements which are lower bounds of $B$, partial order does not guarantee that $L$ will have the greatest element $z$ such that $\forall x\in L(xRz)$.

Or maybe I miss something?

Comment: The problem is correct. Your reason for disbelieving it is incomprehensible. Hint. We assume that $B$ has a smallest element, called $b.$ To show that $b$ is the greatest lower bound of $B,$ we have to show two things. (1) Show that $b$ is ***a*** lower bound of $B.$ That means, show that if $x\in B$ then $b\le x.$ (2) Show that $b$ is the ***greatest*** lower bound of $B.$ That means, show that, if $x$ is any lower bound of $B,$ then $x\le b.$ Both parts follow directly from definitions. (1) What does it mean to be smallest element of $B$? (2)  What does it mean to be lower bound of $B$?

Comment: Existence of such a greatest element is ensured by the existence of $b$: indeed $b$ is larger than any other element of $L$ by definition of $L$.

Comment: See [Greatest lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition) : "the GLB is larger than any other lower bound".

Comment: "The GLB of a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $P$, assuming it exists, does not necessarily belong to $S$. If it does, it is a **minimal** or **least element** of $S$."

Comment: There's no reason to assume that B has a lowest element.  But *if* it does, then that lowest element by definition must be the greatest lower bound.  If b is smallest then it is smaller or equal to all other elements so it is a lower bound.  Anything larger can't be a lower bound because b will be smaller than it.  So b must be greatest lower bound.

Comment: Your are correct that B need not have any lower bounds and if it does it need not have a greatest lower bound.  And B need not have a least element.  BUT if it **does** have a least element, then that least element must be a lower bound.  (As no element is lower).  And it is greatest lower bound (as nothing higher will be a lower bound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set $L$ of lower bounds of $B$. By the definition of a lower bound, for any $l\in L$ and any $b\in B$, we have $l\le b$. But that also implies that any element in $B$ is an upper bound of $L$. That especially is true of the minimum of $B$, if it exists.

So we have: If $b$ is the minimum of $B$, then $b\in L$ and $b$ is an upper bound of $L$. But that's exactly the definition of the maximum.

Thus if $B$ has a minimum, the set of lower bounds of $B$ has a maximum, and that maximum is the minimum of $B$.